# R: remove a subset of a dataframe from the original one with multiple conditions using for loop

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:(`dput` of original table is quite big hence providing a small example)

```
 Date     Sales    Depo
2020-01   100      ABC
2020-02   125      ABC
2020-03   0        ABC
2020-04   0        ABC
2020-01   0        BBC
2020-02   0        BBC
2020-03   0        BBC
2020-04   5        BBC
```

I want to remove all the records pertaining to `BBC` based on the following conditions

```
either the sum(cols) <= max(col_value) or rowcount with zero exceeds 80% of 
   total row count
```

The above rule should be applicable for each `Depo`. 
So the resultant `df` would be

```
 Date     Sales    Depo
2020-01   100      ABC
2020-02   125      ABC
2020-03   0        ABC
2020-04   0        ABC
```

My Approach:

```
df_final = data.frame(Date = NULL,Sales = NULL, Depo =NULL)
for (v in unique(df$Depo)){
     temp <- subset(data,Depo==v)
     temp_f <- temp[,colSums(Sales!=0) > 0]
     df_final <-rbind(df_final,temp_f)
  }
```

But the above gives me a `NULL` data frame

Can anybody throws any light?

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: @jay.sf: Can you please elaborate on this? I am sorry I am completely new to R and thus struggling. My conditions are `either the sum(cols) <= max(col_value) or rowcount with zero exceeds 80% of total row count`. Hope this helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Depo) %>%
  filter((sum(Sales) > max(Sales)) & (sum(Sales == 0) < (0.8 * n())))
  #Opposite can be written as : 
  #filter(!((sum(Sales) <= max(Sales)) | (sum(Sales == 0) > (0.8 * n()))))
```

The same logic can also be implemented in base R :

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(Sales, Depo, FUN = function(x) 
            (sum(x) > max(x)) & (sum(x == 0) < (0.8 * length(x))))))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .SD[(sum(Sales) > max(Sales)) & (sum(Sales == 0) < (0.8 * .N))], Depo]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04", 
"2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04"), Sales = c(100L, 
125L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L), Depo = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
"ABC", "BBC", "BBC", "BBC", "BBC")), class = "data.frame", row.names =c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Yes, it will remove the entire group which satisfies the criteria.

Comment: This is giving me an error as Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Comment: @pythondumb In my answer I am not trying to convert any column to `POSIXlt` actually. I have updated the post with the data I am using which does not give me any error. Please check how your real data is different than the data you have shared. You can update your post with `dput` of your data so that we can reproduce the results at our end.

Comment: Ok.I tackled the same by simply converting the resulting data into `as.data.frame()` But now I am getting another error: `Error in Summary.factor(c(14L, 49L, 26L, 35L, 214L, 168L, 2L, 103L, 1L,  :  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors`. Any Clue?

Comment: yes, I think `Sales` is factors. Can you first run `df$Sales <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Sales))` and then try the above.